# How to debug PHP,Javascript code in Sublime Text3?

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, sublimetext3, wampserver

i am using WAMP server and i am working with Windows7 operating system.

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

zend_extension="C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.9-1/ext/php_xdebug-2.0.4-5.2.8.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

i have made changes in php.ini file as shown above

Comment: please be specific about the thing you want??

Comment: i want to debug the php code in sublime. thats it..

Comment: Have you tried to use [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=sublime+text+xdebug)? Just to clarify: Sublime Text is a text editor. For developing applications you should use an IDE.

Comment: ya i tried with google and what is an IDE? where i can find it and how to use it?.. @Kyoya

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/

Answer (score 2):

Configure xdebug on your WAMP server (looks like you have already done that).

Then, you will need to use [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) in Sublime Text 3 to install the [Xdebug Client](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug) package (use the martomo version, not the kindari version). You might need to install Package Control if you have not already.

Here is a more in-depth tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/